# Confuse about ( Form attribute )

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm confused about using the form attribute (Form=" ")

From **MDN**

> An input can be associated with at most one form.

From **W3S**

> The form attribute specifies one or more forms an  element
>   belongs to.
>  To refer to more than one form, use a
>   space-separated list of form ids.

So,Can i associate an input with more than one form ? or not ?
 Which one is true ?

Comment: An input is tied to one form as far as I know. Will look for RFC... A good rule of thumb is  everything on W3C is wrong.

Comment: Ugh. Meant w3schools.

Answer (score 4):

**No..** The `from` attribute did not exist prior to HTML5's release. You will need to look at your `DOCTYPE` and make that determination.

Before HTML5, you could use Javascript and do some stuff with Xhr to accomplish that type of behavior if it was actually needed however.

I found the example [you cited](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)...

```
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1">
```

Here is the description in HTML5 Form Specs:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-formelements-form

> This feature allows authors to work around the lack of support for
>   nested form elements.
>
> If a reassociateable form-associated element has a form attribute
>   specified, then that attribute’s value must be the ID of a form
>   element in the element’s owner Document.

Quite a few other comments in the RFC. Recommend taking a look there.

Good article: https://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

**Updated**
after more consideration not seeing anything which suggests a form attribute can specify more than one form. Most concise text from W3C spec to support that would be: *"form - Associates the control with **a** form element"*.

Comment: sorry i am a beginner on learning html
so have you any simple answer or explanation ?

Comment: @ficuscr - But w3schools.com is just wrong on this point. It says that the form attribute can be space-separated list of ids. But as your quote from the HTML5 spec makes clear, it must be a single id. So only one form can ever be associated with a control at any one time,

Comment: @Alohci I'll admit I'm still a bit confused about that also. Seems like specs still prohibit nested `<form>` elements still also. But I agree, most of those other "rules" seem to be about maintaining a single association.

Comment: Yes, it does. That's what the form attribute is mainly for, to get around the fact that forms can't be nested in the `text/html` serialization. Note that you *can* nest forms in the DOM and in the `application/xhtml+xml` serialization. but it is still non-conforming (i.e. invalid) to do so.

Comment: @ficuscr
may you give me your facebook acc or any thing or anything i can contact it with you ?

Comment: @KaremGmeay Twitter handle is in bio.